# How to empty the trash?

Tags: macos, mac, trash

There is a strange file in my Trash that doesn't go away when I empty the trash.  The file name looks like:

```
␀␀␀õ␀␀.õ␀
```

The file is apparently in /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/ ("NO NAME" is my boot camp Windows volume, so I'm not even sure why it has a .Trashes directory.  If I try to "ls" that file, or even that directory, I get:

```
ls: \004␀␀␀õ\001␀␀.õ\001␀: File name too long
```

The same thing happens if I try "sudo ls -le", "sudo ls -la" or "sudo ls -i".

And similar results when I try to rm it or even "find . -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 rm"

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: would be good to check permissions for it, what do you get for ls -le?

Comment: @cobbal, You'll note that I already mentioned using "sudo" to attempt to remove it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This person](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/windows-classic-linux-other-os/102926-i-need-unix-help-3.html#post627971) had the same problem, and fixed it by performing a disk check in Windows.

Comment: Amazing that they had almost exactly the same bogus filename too.  I think there must be a bug in the Mac OS FAT32 file system driver that allows something out there to create a file that shouldn't be possible to create on a FAT32 file system.

Answer (score 3):

one thing to try would be using lower level calls than ls to list the directory

```
python -c 'import os; print repr(os.listdir("/Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/"))'
```

and if that works, maybe try using the `unlink()` function

edit: to unlink try

```
python -c 'import os; os.unlink("/Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/\x04\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80.o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80")'
```

Comment: That works, (returns ['\x04\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80.o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80']) but I don't know python so I don't know how to use it to unlink the file.  I guess I'll have to try it in perl.

Comment: Perl doesn't seem to do it.  sudo perl -e 'opendir DIR, "."; while ($line = readdir(DIR)) { print "\n[", $line, "]\n"; unlink($line);}' ends up listing the file, but not deleting it.

Comment: Result from trying to delete it in python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '/Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/\x04\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80.o\xcc\x83\x01\xe2\x90\x80'

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting by inode?

```
ls -i
```

will show the files and their inode numbers

```
$ ls -i *.log
 694197 alf.log         694719 mb.log
 694181 fsck_hfs.log     24190 secure.log
 802696 hdiejectd.log   694195 system.log
1094966 install.log     694396 windowserver.log
  24189 ipfw.log
```

Then use find to remove by inode (say I wanted to delete mb.log from above):

```
find . -inum 694719 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "ls -i" has the same problem:
 ls -i
ls: \004␀␀␀õ\001␀␀.õ\001␀: File name too long

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting in to Windows, and see if it can delete the file (assuming it can actually see it).

Comment: Windows will not read HFS+ partition without aid of proprietary tools. To add insult to injury, it's read only too.

Comment: He said it was his boot camp volume, so it should be readable by Windows.